# Subtracting timestamps in PHP starting in and keeping this format: 00:00:00

Tags: php, timestamp

I have 2 strings:

```
$time1 = '00:00:10';
$time2 = '00:00:04';
```

Using PHP, how can I subtract $time1 from $time2 so that I end up with:

```
$time3 = '00:00:06';
```

Comment: Have you looked at the PHP time functions, http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but first you need to convert those timestamps to `int` format to be able to subtract them.

```
$time1_timestamp = strtotime($time1);
$time2_timestamp = strtotime($time2);

$time3 = $time1_timestamp - $time2_timestamp;
```

And then convert it back into `hh:mm:ss` format:

```
$time3 = date('H:i:s', $time3);
```